# ViewerJS The server refused the connection

Tags: php, html, cpanel, web-hosting

noob question...

I have incorporated [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/) in my website

Code:

```
 <iframe src = "http://localhost/VADHOD//ViewerJS/#../pdf/UthMaio.pdf" width = "750" height='900' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It working fine on my localhost on XAMPP server

But when i uploaded to my hosting provider 000webhost...

It doesnt load and shows

> The server refused the connection

Do i need to activate php somehow on cPanel like I start Apache service in my xampp control panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your link URL... You have set it to localhost .. Remove that

```
<iframe src = "/ViewerJS/#../pdf/UthMaio.pdf" width = "750" height='900' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Not working... it loads the frame but doesnt actually load the pdf just shows name... please help

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that you need to check/verify here:

- you can try to replace localhost with the actual IP address or server
  hostname/domain that you have with your hosting provider;
- you need to make sure that the path is correct;
- please pay attention to the names of the folders and files as in unix/linux (I assume you are on a linux server) paths are case sensitive and capital letters matter;

Comment: thank u bro,, that was the problem... path was to localhost even on webserver... then how will it work...so stupid of me